# average the values of a column

Tags: gnuplot, average

I'm pretty new to this forum.

I have a problem with a gnuplot script. I want the program to read from a file and take the average of the data in a column but just of two subsequent rows.

This is an example of my data file:

```
10972710;0;97;11699;75114829;14017;62910343;4294966568;71227698;4294690030;17218646
10972710;1;98;4294694062;75242152;4294781521;62921071;4294614770;71144038;4294733461;18276743
10972710;0;99;117245;75164467;4294946663;62862643;49062;71038638;4294745782;17886802
10972710;1;100;4294799584;75123654;4294686842;63040946;4294609337;71224369;4294706709;17333245
10972710;0;101;1845;75045355;46741;62966683;72313;71243339;4294713057;18914555
10972809;1;102;4294963298;75210462;59798;63318000;4587;71262619;70880;19513152
10972809;0;103;4294957708;75074862;33562;63074526;189991;71061923;39240;18642066
```

For example, focusing on the 4th column I want to perform the average of the 1st row with the 2nd, the 3rd with the 4th and so on. Is there some built-in function in gnuplot or do I have to write my own?

Thank you so much.

Tommaso

Comment: Accessing two different rows in gnuplot isn't so straightforward. What should be the x-value if you compute the average of the fourth column in the 1st and 2nd row?

Comment: At the moment I'm using the first column, but actually I don't care about the x-value. I can just put a progressive index to the average value and use it as the x-value.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple operations on ajacent rows are possible with gnuplot: You must save the value of one row using an assignment in the `using` statement, and the plot only every second point:

```
set datafile separator ';'
prev = curr = 0
plot 'test.txt' using (int($0)/2):(prev = curr, curr = $4, int($0)%2 == 1 ? (curr - prev)/2.0 : 1/0) with linespoints
```

The using statement works as follows, first you assign the value of the previous row (which is at that point still in `curr`) to the variable `prev`, then you assign the value of the current row to `curr` and finally do the average if you are on an odd row number (rows start at 0), or give an invalid point with `1/0`.

The result with version 5.0 is

[image]

As you see, you get only points although I specified `linespoints`. The invalid `1/0` make gnuplot interrupt the lines here, so no lines are plotted.

With gnuplot 5.0 you can save the result of the filtering to a temporary file (or also to a heredoc structure, the `$avg`) and plot that processed data with a second call:

```
set datafile separator ';'

prev = curr = 0

set table $avg
plot 'test.txt' using (int($0)/2):(prev = curr, curr = $4, int($0)%2 == 1 ? (curr - prev)/2.0 : 1/0) with lp pt 7
unset table

set datafile separator whitespace
plot $avg using 1:2 w lp
```

Note, that this wouldn't work with version 4.6, since this version has a different handling of parsing data files with `NaN` inside, like the one which is generated by gnuplot.

Finally, you can also use an external tool like `awk` to do the processing for you, like

```
plot '< awk -F";" "{if (NR%2 == 0) { printf \"%.10e\n\", (\$4-prev)/2.0 }; prev = \$4}" test.txt' using 0:1 with linespoints
```